# getcwd() is faulty when in a programmed launched by abspath

Tags: python, bash, directory, alias, getcwd

### Error

When an alias of python command runs on a file defined with an **absolute path**, its `getcwd()` becomes faulty, i.e. it doesn't represent my current location from which I'm running this script.

### Reproduce

Add the following two lines to `~/.bashrc`

```
cd /<DEFAULT_DIR>/
alias lds='python -c "import os; print(os.getcwd())"'
alias ld='python /<ABS_DIR_LOCATION>/ld.py'
```

with `ld.py`:

```
import os;
print(os.getcwd())
```

Init bash and run:

```
> cd /<NOT-DEFAULT-DIR>/
> lds 
/<NOT-DEFAULT-DIR>/
> ld
/<DEFAULT_DIR>/
```

Comment: cant find my .bashrc  ? Are you sure it exist ?

Comment: @pippo1980 Are you using `bash` as your interactive shell? If you don't have a `.bashrc`, it will use `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: This only happens when you use aliases?

Comment: mmh dont have that too, I use cmd.exe to get the term

Comment: @pippo1980 `bash` is the shell on Unix, not Windows.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on MacOS, I got `/<NOT-DEFAULT-DIR>/` in both cases.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I have the same dir in both cases.

Comment: I also can't reproduce it now - it should have been a server bug on the server I'm working on, but I don't know why. I leave it here in case someone has this bug / discovers what can lead to such a problematic behavior in the future :) (thank you for your answers - a hint may be that my home dir had no space left - but I have no clue whether this can actually play a role :/)